# withings api authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, oauth

I am trying to authenticate with the withings api. I have got the consumer key and secret correctly and am able to get to the app page, and I can also authenticate with the api.

The problem is that it is not coming back, instead showing a 404 error: page not found.
I have cross-checked the callback url many times.

Here's the [url](http://oauth.withings.com/account/authorize?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fwithings%2Fcallback&oauth_token=3659f7e3c3eccbfc6990fe5f194d4c947783b1544755c6147f380813231).

This is the code I am trying to authenticate with: [Documentation](http://www.withings.com/en/api/oauthguide#registration), [Gem1](https://github.com/simplificator/simplificator-withings), [Gem2](https://github.com/webmonarch/withings-api).

I want to get the user back to my application.

```
@callback_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/withings/callback'
    @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(WITHINGS_KEY, WITHINGS_SECRET, {
        :site => 'https://oauth.withings.com',
        :request_token_path => '/account/request_token',
        :access_token_path => '/account/access_token',
        :authorize_path => '/account/authorize'
    })
    @request_token = @consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => @callback_url)
    session[:request_token] = @request_token
    redirect_to @request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => @callback_url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. I think, you should not use third-party libraries, because

```
@request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => @callback_url)
```

return incorrect url.

Try to make your own implementation of OAuth.

1) Use HMAC-SHA1 algorithm for string:

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Foauth.withings.com%2Faccount%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fwithings%2Fcallback%26oauth_consumer_key%3D{WITHINGS KEY}%26oauth_nonce%3D{RANDOM STRING}%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D{CURRENT TIME}%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

This string contains 3 parts:
{METHOD} + "&" + {ENCODED REQUEST URL} + "&" + {ENCODED REQUEST QUERY PART}

SECRET KEY for signing: {WITHINGS SECRET}+"&"

In result encode this sign.

2) Send request to the URL:

```
https://oauth.withings.com/account/request_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fwithings%2Fcallback&oauth_consumer_key={WITHINGS KEY}&oauth_nonce={NONCE FROM STEP 1}&oauth_signature={RESULT OF STEP 1}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp={TIMESTAMP FROM STEP 1}&oauth_version=1.0
```

3) Parse response body. Get OAUTH TOKEN and OAUTH SECRET.

4) Use HMAC-SHA1 algorithm for string:

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Foauth.withings.com%2Faccount%2Fauthorize&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fwithings%2Fcallback%26oauth_consumer_key%3D{SECRET KEY}%26oauth_nonce%3D{RANDOM STRING}%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_token%3D{OAUTH TOKEN}%26oauth_timestamp%3D{CURRENT TIME}%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

SECRET KEY for signing: {WITHINGS SECRET}+"&" + {OAUTH SECRET}

In result encode this sign.

5) Redirect user to the URL:

```
https://oauth.withings.com/account/rauthorize?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fwithings%2Fcallback&oauth_consumer_key={WITHINGS KEY}&oauth_nonce={NONCE FROM STEP 4}&oauth_signature={RESULT OF STEP 4}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_token={OAUTH TOKEN}&oauth_timestamp={TIMESTAMP FROM STEP 4}&oauth_version=1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are missing oauth_consumer_key, oauth_signature and other oauth fields in the example link.

Comment: WITHINGS_KEY and WITHINGS_SECRET are the consumer key and consumer secret. Withings din't gave any oauth_signature, It gave ony consumer key and secret

Comment: Yes. But look at the example request from the documentation. A request must contain next fields:
oauth_callback (encoded redirect url), 
oauth_consumer_key (WITHINGS_KEY), 
oauth_nonce  (random string), 
oauth_signature  (request signing with Consumer Secret), 
oauth_signature_method  (signing method (HMAC-SHA1)), 
oauth_timestamp  (current time), 
oauth_token  (request token received from https://oauth.withings.com/account/request_token), 
oauth_version  (1.0).

Comment: is the call_back required to be a live site, in order to get the response?  I'm getting an error 500 and wondering if I now need a live site up.