# Withings API No Response on request_token

Tags: http, oauth, withings

I have setup everything as described in the steps in answer to the post [withings api authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129751/withings-api-authentication).

However, when i copy and paste the final URL generated in Step 2 (Send request to the URL:), I get no response on my browser and the screen remains empty.

Is there any reason for why it might be happening ?
OAUTH TOKEN and OAUTH SECRET - will I get two of them appended to callback url ?

Comment: I am getting java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://oauth.withings.com/account/request_token?oauth_callback={my call back url}&oauth_consumer_key={my consumer key}&oauth_nonce={my random string}&oauth_signature={my generated signature}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp={my current timestamp}oauth_version=1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each paramter  string was supposed to be URL encoded in signature i.e URLEncoder.encode("key=value","UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

I have used temboo API to get the user tokens.
They have two steps Initial oauth and final oauth.

Comment: Can you provide an example, please

Comment: Example using temboo??? well with developers tokens its fairly straight forward on their site once you register. I am Not sure what example you want